# Incorrect Val Loss from Keras during training

Tags: keras

Keras seems to be reporting an incorrect val loss during training. When I train the model, it reports a val MSE loss of around 0.88. When I immediately reload the model and run the .predict method on the exact same validation set, I get a val MSE loss of around 1.2. I have checked the weights to ensure that the post-training model is identical to the reloaded model. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? Thanks!

Code:

```
training_data = data[:10000]
training_norm_factor = np.std(training_data)
training_mean = np.mean(training_data)
training_inputs = training_data[:,:-1].reshape((-1, look_back, 1))
training_inputs = (training_inputs - training_mean)/training_norm_factor
training_labels = (training_data[:,-1] - training_mean)/training_norm_factor

val_data = data[10000:]
val_inputs = val_data[:, :-1].reshape((-1, look_back, 1))
val_inputs = (val_inputs - training_mean)/training_norm_factor
val_labels = (val_data[:,-1] - training_mean)/training_norm_factor

# Build Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(256, input_shape=(5, 1), return_sequences=True, 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(layers.GRU(256, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))


# Compile and Train
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-3, clipnorm=1.),
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              )

callbacks_list = [
    K.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=0), K.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('/Users/rickblickstead/Documents/GitHub/Volatility-
                Forecasting/MyModel.5df5', 
                monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, 
                mode='min', period=1)
]

history = model.fit(training_inputs[:, -5:], training_labels,
                    epochs=8,
                    batch_size=256,
                    shuffle=True,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list,
                    validation_data = (val_inputs[:, -5:], val_labels)
                   )

# Re-Test validation set

best_model = load_model('MyModel.5df5')
best_predictions = best_model.predict(val_inputs[:, -5:], batch_size=256, verbose=0)
print np.mean((best_predictions-val_labels)**2)
```

Comment: Is `val_labels` an 1D-array? If `val_labels` is of shape `(M,)` and `best_predictions` is of shape `(M, 1)`, then `best_predictions - val_labels` will be a `(M, M)` matrix. Taking mean over the matrix does not give you MSE. Try `np.mean((best_predictions.ravel() - val_labels)**2)` instead.

Comment: Also, since you're using L2-regularization, the printed `val_loss` during training should be higher than MSE alone.

Comment: Thank you SO much! That's exactly what I was doing wrong. You've just helped me escape from days of frustration!